# GWT - What to put in the shared folder?

Tags: gwt, shared

I'm still unsure on what to put into the `shared` folder. If I'm doing RPC requests, and sending Pojos from the client to the server and vice versa, do I have to put them into the `shared` folder (because they are used by both - client and server).

**EDIT**

Maybe I've used the wrong term but when I said `Pojo` I actually meant `DTO`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to put the RPC POJOs in a `shared` folder but if you keep them in the `client` folder, the server would be dependent on the client package because the Pojos are used both by the client and the server. It's definitely better to have client and server strictly separated, and that's what the `shared` folder is for.

The stuff I would put into the `shared` folder is:

- RPC requests / responses - I'm using the Command pattern (gwt-dispatch)
- Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) - lightweight objects used to transfer data
- Input validators - logic that is shared during client-side and server-side validation
- Shared configuration

Answer (score 2):

The shared folder must contain only code that needs to be shared both by the client and the server side. Keep in mind that this code **must** be executable client side, so you don't have access to some of the Java classes.

So basically any POJO or DTO class should be in the shared folder.

Comment: Maybe you meant DTO classes? DAOs should definitely NOT be in the shared folder because they would most likely contain logic for DB communication..