# No source code is available for type. did you forget to inherit a required module

Tags: java, gwt, rpc

sorry for my English
I have an GWT project.
I wont to  use server classes on client side.

I have RPC service that returns object "Route"

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("springGwtServices/RouteService")
public interface IRouteService extends RemoteService {
    public ArrayList<Route> searchRoutes(String from, String to);
}
```

but I cant use this class on client side.
When I tried to import this, I get exception "Route cannot be resolved to a type"
Can I use this class on server?
If I cant, what I must to do? 
p.s.
I put all needed classes to share folder and get exception

```
No source code is available for type project.shared.Route; did you forget to inherit a required module
```

Answer (score 5):

There will be a package called `shared` where you can use those classes both on server and client side.

You cannot use `server` packaged classes on client side.

And be careful before you putting something in shared package. Have a read [GWT - What to put in the shared folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664601/gwt-what-to-put-in-the-shared-folder)

Comment: Thanks.What I must to do if I wont to use POJOs on client side?

Comment: @ZaichenkoDenis put then in shared package

Comment: @ZaichenkoDenis What is not working ? Show your Route class?  And also update your *gwt.xml file too

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you have `<source path="shared"/>` in your *gwt.xml

Comment: That would be a comment :)

Comment: To comment reputation score must be 50 :)